# What string should I pass to java.lang.Long.parseLong() to return a NaN?

Tags: java, long-integer, nan

I unfortunately cant use expressions like Long.Nan as the string is actually a return value from a different C module. Is there a string I can pass to parseLong() to return an NaN ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no Long.NaN -- you are confused.

For Double.NaN, how about this:

```
public double myParseDouble(String s)
{
   double result;
   try
   {
      result = Double.parseDouble(s);
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
   {
      result = Double.NaN;
   }
   return result;
}
```

(edit: and the obvious approach is to pass in any string that is an invalid double, e.g. the empty string or NaN)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as [`Long`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)`.NaN`, which makes sense when you consider that every bit pattern within long represents a valid integer within the range of [`Long.MIN_VALUE`, `Long.MAX_VALUE`].

You might consider trying to get the bit pattern of [`Double.NaN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Long.Nan? That doesn't exist in Java. You only have Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE

"Nan" as argument to `Double.parseDouble(String)` gives Double.NaN as value if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.Long` represent 64-bit signed integral value, while `NaN` is introduced only in floating-point computations. That being said there is no special string return Long `NaN`, but you can for instance use:

```
double notANumber = java.lang.Double.NaN;
```

Answer (score 1):

Java only has a concept of NaN for floating point datatypes, not integer ones such as `Long`.